# How to sync 2 directory content on 2 different computer during file change only

Tags: windows, copy, robocopy

Lets say I have PC A(with folder C:\PCA) and PC B (with folder C:\PCB)

first i do a WNetAddConnection2 to map PCB folder on PC A with S drive letter
followed by a copy command cmd.exe /C copy S:*.* C:\PCA\ /Y

but this will be just copy all files in PCB to PCA everytime i call it

I'm looking for a way to Sync PCA and PCB (One way is ok) and the process should copy only files with changes(to save bandwidth).

Answer (score 0):

This type of action could be performed on Linux with a tool called `rsync`

Maybe try take a look at this answer:

https://superuser.com/questions/69514/windows-alternative-to-rsync

for some Windows alternatives.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i'm running windows on the 2 PC